How do I fix these sharp edegs and verticies on my model?
**So I have this problem with this model i am making. The model's arms have sharp edges on them in certain places and when i go into edit mode, I see that in those areas the verticies arent connected no problem, i just connect them. However when i do that the poly juts out i different directions from the body. When I go back into edit mode those lines and verticies are no where to be found. I also have multiresolution as a modd if that helps at all. I'm still new to blender so im still learning the ropes of things.

[

Hello try an Alt H in Edit mode in order to unhide, if it doesn't work please share your file
